# Where do I find custom maps in Trackmania when playing on Linux

Tags: steam, linux, trackmania-forever

I am playing Trackmania: Nations Forever on steam, but my system is Arch Linux. And I cant find anywhere to put my custom maps. Where are they stored?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the arqade!

While I don't know how TMNF installs on Linux, I can give you some hints as to how to find the location. I wanted to post this as a comment at first for that reason, but it would have been hard to read.

#### Idea 1

On Windows, downloaded maps for TMNF are put in this dir:

```
C:\Users\<username>\Documents\TmForever\Tracks\Challenges\Downloaded
```

By that logic, you could look if `~/Documents/TmForever/...` exists.

#### Idea 2

Create a map using the map editor and save it. It needn't be any good, it just has to have a name. Then, search for it using something like

```
find ~/ -name "<trackname>.Challenge.Gbx"
```

You might have to fiddle with capitalisation; if all fails, start the search at `/` and search for `<trackname>*`

Created maps are stored near the place you'd put your downloaded maps, i.e.

```
.../TmForever/Tracks/Challenges/
                                My Challenges/<trackname>.Challenge.Gbx
                                Downloaded/<PLACE TRACKS HERE>
```

HTH